# underscore: can it build an array by passing a total and an object?

Tags: underscore.js

I'm curious if I could use underscore to build dummy data like so:

```
var things = [];

for (var i = 10; i--; ) {
   var thing = { id: i };
   things.push( thing ) 
}
```

Is that possible with underscore? Is there some function where I could pass in a total and an object and get back an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`_.times`](http://underscorejs.org/#times):

> **times** `_.times(n, iterator, [context])`
>
> Invokes the given iterator function **n** times. Each invocation of **iterator** is called with an *index* argument. Produces an array of the returned values.

So:

```
var things = _(10).times(function(i) { return { id: i + 1 } });
```

or if you need them in the same order as your `for` loop:

```
var things = _(10).times(function(i) { return { id: i + 1 } })
                  .reverse();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/arZB8/

Comment: @thefourtheye `_.f(x)` and `_(x).f()` do the same thing, I think the latter is prettier and reads better.

Comment: But how does it do? `_` is basically an object, so how does `_(x)` work?

Comment: @thefourtheye: A function is an object too, so is a constructor function. Maybe the annotated source would be a good starting place: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-9

Comment: It still looks like a magic to me. I put in `console.log` inside the constructor and `_.times`, the above code passes 10 to the first parameter, even when we don't do that explicitly.

Comment: mmm It internally calls `_.mixin` function and there the value 10 is applied. Now trying to understand how that `_.mixin` is getting called.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Keep any on `this._wrapped` in `_()` and then `var args = [this._wrapped]; push.apply(args, arguments);` inside the `_.mixin` stuff, that's how the first argument magically gets into `_.times`. So `_(x).f()` is slightly more expensive than `_.f(x)` but readability boost outweighs the expense in my eyes.

Comment: Oops... I got that and I forgot to mention it here. Thanks a lot for taking your time to explain this :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: No worries, the Underscore source is worth reading, it is pretty easy to follow for the most part and has some neat stuff in it.

Comment: Underscore is awesome :) I bought [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028857.do) and reading it whenever I find time